# SQL throws syntax error where the code has FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('(./text())[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')

Tags: sql, azure-synapse

Getting the following error:

> Parse error at line: 69, column: 33: Incorrect syntax near 'FOR'.

Not able to understand what the issue is Is aggregate string concatenation not supported?

Code:

```
SELECT 
    STUFF((SELECT
               -- Prepend with delimiter and escape internal delimiters
               DIMENSIONSEGMENTDELIMITER)
          FROM
              (SELECT TOP (1) DH.RECID
               FROM dw.DIMENSIONHIERARCHY DH
               JOIN dw.DIMENSIONHIERARCHYINTEGRATION DHI
                       ON DHI.DIMENSIONHIERARCHY = DH.RECID
                       AND DHI.ISDEFAULT = 1
                       --AND DHI.PARTITION = T1.PARTITION
               WHERE
                   --DH.PARTITION = T1.PARTITION
                   DH.STRUCTURETYPE = 17) AS DH
          JOIN dw.DIMENSIONHIERARCHYLEVEL DHL
                  ON DHL.DIMENSIONHIERARCHY = DH.RECID 
          JOIN dw.DIMENSIONATTRIBUTE DA
                  ON DA.RECID = DHL.DIMENSIONATTRIBUTE 
          LEFT JOIN
              (SELECT DIMENSIONATTRIBUTE, DISPLAYVALUE
               FROM
                   (SELECT * 
                    FROM dw.DIMENSIONATTRIBUTEVALUESET DAVS
                    --WHERE DAVS.PARTITION = T1.PARTITION 
                    --AND DAVS.RECID = T1.RECID
                   ) P
               UNPIVOT
                   (DISPLAYVALUE for DIMENSIONATTRIBUTE IN (D1_BUSINESSLINEVALUE, D2_SITEVALUE, D3_DEPARTMENTVALUE, D4_COSTCENTERVALUE, D5_PURPOSEVALUE)) AS DIMENSIONVALUECOLUMNNAME
              ) AS DIMLIST
                   ON DIMLIST.DIMENSIONATTRIBUTE = REPLACE(DA.DIMENSIONVALUECOLUMNNAME COLLATE Database_Default, '.', '$')
                            ORDER BY DHL.DIMENSIONHIERARCHY, DHL.LEVEL_
                            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                        ).value('(./text())[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),
                        1, LEN(DIMENSIONSEGMENTDELIMITER), '')

                     AS NonNullDisplayValue
```

Comment: What are you using?- azure synapse- dedicated SQL pool or azure sql database?

Comment: azure synapse dedicated pool

Answer (score 1):

If you are using dedicated SQL pool in synapse as per [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-for-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) It is not supported. I tried to replicate the situation in my dedicated sql pool with sample data.
I created table inserted values

```
create table tab1 (id int, name varchar(100))
insert into tab1 values(1,'AA')
insert into tab1 values(2,'BB')  
select * from tab1
```

[image]

I tried to create XML data by using For XML Auto

```
select * from tab1 where id>0 for xml path
```

I got the same error.

[image]

In synapse dedicated SQL pool, we can use **concat** and **string_agg** functions and create xml data manually instead of using **For XML auto**

I tried with below Query to convert the table data in XML format:

```
select  string_agg(concat('<row><id>',id,'</id>','<name>',name,'</name></row>'),' ') as XML_data from tab1 where id > 0
```

Result:

[image]